# Moving Github Enterprise to GitHub

Tags: github

I have a couple of private repositories where I am the only contributor under Github Enterprise through my university. I am wondering, how can I add my GitHub open (personal) account as a contributor, or alternatively move the repositories from the Enterprise to the Github Open account?

I am aware of where to go to add collaborators, but I cannot find my Github Open username when I search it in the Enterprise github.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by:

1. Creating a new repo under your GitHub personal account,
2. Then, using the command line to set your new repo's URL as a `remote` to your local copy of your Enterprise repo,
3. Finally, force pushing all contents to the new public repo.

Once you've created your new personal repo, grab its URL like so:

[image: get github repository url]

Then, using the command line, `cd` into your local copy of your Enterprise repo and ensure it's up-to-date via `git checkout master` and `git pull origin master` (or whatever your desired master branch is named).

Run [this command](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/) to add your new public GitHub repo as a `remote` repository:

```
git remote add public https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Finally, do a force push to your public GitHub repo to push all of your Enterprise repo's contents to it:

```
git push -f public
```

Comment: Found this while looking for similar question. I am trying to connect my enterprise repo to DBeaver and push my code directly. How can I do it? I can connect my personal repo but not enterprise repo. Do I need to purchase license?

Comment: I'd recommend asking a new question to get the most eyes on it - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Anyone reading into transferring "GitHub Enterprise" repository in 2022, there has been an update in GitHub which enables you to transfer the project only using GitHub pages (Enterprise & Personal) and avoids using CMD (command prompt).**

**Doing this step will automatically cast contributors (If their account is linked to a personal one as well as the Enterprise account), issues & history of the project to your new repository.**

**Steps to Complete it:**

1. Go to your "Personal GitHub account"
2. Make a new repository -> select a name that you wish the project to be called.
3. Do not add any " Git ignore / read.me files into your project (It has to be empty!) & Select it to be a public repository.
4. On the empty project page, scroll down to " Import Code " click on it.
5. Opens up with a new page, where you are required to enter your "GitHub Enterprise link https://enterprise.name.ac.uk/MyProject.git <-- This will be different for you!
6. Press " Begin Import "
7. Which will then prompt you with a log in for (GitHub Enterprise account), which you are required to enter correctly for it to work, once entered it should start importing
8. You are then prompted with a panel asking which of the projects you would like to import attached to your Enterprise URL, select one of them and click " Submit ".
9. Once the transfer has finished you will get an e-mail that states that the import has been finished which provides you with a link to your new repository page!

**Enjoy!**

[Further Read into Official Github Importing Steps.](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer)